# Making a portion of the canvas link to another webpage

Tags: javascript, canvas

I currently have a code that simply draws circles onto a canvas. However, I want those circles to be able to direct the user to a given link if he or she chooses to click on the circle again. I'm not entirely sure how to implement this though. Simply put, can drawn objects be used as a click event to direct user to another webpage?

http://jsfiddle.net/PTDy9/

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<img id="graph" style=display:none src="http://i47.tinypic.com/29zr14o.jpg" alt="graph" >

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="400" style="border:1px solid #FFFFF;">

<script>
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas"); 
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d"); 
        var img=document.getElementById("graph"); 
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); 
        var color_list = ["#FFC0CB", "#00ffff", "#DA70D6", "#90EE90", "#FF8C00", "#CD853F"];
        var color_iter = 0;
        var bullet_y = 450;
        var width = img.naturalWidth;
        var height = img.naturalHeight;
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
             $("#myCanvas").click(function(e){ 

                var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop; 

                if (x < width && y < height) {
                    var ctx= this.getContext("2d"); 
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x, y, 10,0, 2*Math.PI);
                    color = color_list[color_iter];
                    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
                    ctx.fillStyle = color;
                    if (color_iter == color_list.length-1) {
                        color_iter = 0;
                        }
                    else {color_iter = color_iter + 1;}
                    ctx.fillStyle = color;
                    ctx.globalAlpha = .4;
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.stroke();
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    }
           }); 
        }) 
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's one way let the user click on a circle to open a specified url in a new browser tab.**

First create 1+ link objects specifying the click area on the canvas and the desired url:

```
var links=[];

addLink(75,75,30,"Google","http://www.google.com");
addLink(150,150,30,"CNN","http://www.cnn.com");

function addLink(x,y,radius,label,url){
    links.push({
        cx:x, 
        cy:y, 
        radius:radius,
        label:label,
        link:url
    });
}
```

Then listen for mouse clicks and test if any link area was clicked.

If any specific link area was clicked, then open up the corresponding url in a new browser tab:

```
$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

function handleMouseDown(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

    for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
        var link=links[i];
        var dx=link.cx-mx;
        var dy=link.cy-my;
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<link.radius*link.radius){
            window.open(link.link,'_blank');
        }
    }
}
```

Full Example Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
    var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

    var links=[];

    addLink(75,75,30,"Google","http://www.google.com");
    addLink(150,150,30,"CNN","http://www.cnn.com");

    drawLinks();

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

    function addLink(x,y,radius,label,url){
        links.push({
            cx:x, 
            cy:y, 
            radius:radius,
            label:label,
            link:url
        });
    }

    function drawLinks(){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle="green";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.font="14px verdana";
        ctx.textAlign="center";
        ctx.textBaseline="middle";
        for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
            var link=links[i];
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(link.cx,link.cy,link.radius,0,Math.PI*2);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle="blue";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.fillStyle="white";
            ctx.fillText(link.label,link.cx,link.cy);
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }


    function handleMouseDown(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

        for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
            var link=links[i];
            var dx=link.cx-mx;
            var dy=link.cy-my;
            if(dx*dx+dy*dy<link.radius*link.radius){
                window.open(link.link,'_blank');
            }
        }
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the link area is always defined by me. Is it possible to make the link area user defined. As in, it can be anywhere where the user clicks as long as it's inside the canvas.

Comment: Sure...much easier.  Just listen for mousedown in the canvas and then do:  window.open( yourURL ,'_blank');

Comment: Sorry for not explaining fully. I think I should clarify more..I'm trying to build a website kind of like a forum. For each comment that people post, they each gain a respective circle - so it's like a list of URLs that pertains to each post that I have. Each time a poster clicks on the graph, their post will be linked do that specific area on the graph. However, what you're suggesting is that other users wouldn't be able to click on a specific circle and go to that specific post.

Comment: So do I understand that you want to make circular links instead of rectangular links? See my updated answer that uses circles instead of rectangles as the link areas.

Comment: Thank you, here's a check for you :)